# What zen coding expression expand to <input type="hidden" name="FieldName"/>?

Tags: emmet

What zen coding expression expand to `<input type="hidden" name="FieldName"/>`?

Answer (score 1):

The following expression

```
input:hidden[name=FieldName]
```